# dotnet test command to display individual test run times?

Tags: .net-core, mstest

I am switching from javascript Mocha to the MSTest framework with .NET Core 3.x.

Currently running `dotnet test` displays:

`Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     6, Skipped:     0, Total:     6, Duration: 521 ms`

Is there a way I can get it to display similar to Mocha?

```
TestClass1
  TestMethod1 (51ms)
  TestMethod2 (100ms)
  TestMethod3 (24ms)

TestClass2
  TestMethod1 (115ms)
  TestMethod2 (55ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following to get a similar output.

```
dotnet test -l "console;verbosity=detailed"
```

Comment: Works perfect thanks! Didn't know I could pass in the console to the logger parameter.